# In spring validation getting NotReadablePropertyException. getters are not found message is showing. please clarify about controler arguments

Tags: java, spring, validation, spring-mvc

Iam trying to do validation for a form. so iam getting confused about command name, model, modelandview, modelMap @modelAttribute. can you please fix the following error. and give some clarity about this error

Pojo Class:

```
public class UserLogin implements Serializable {

private Integer associateId;
private String associateName;
private String associateRole;
private String associateMobileNumber;

public Integer getAssociateId() {
    return associateId;
}

public void setAssociateId(Integer associateId) {
    this.associateId = associateId;
}

public String getAssociateName() {
    return associateName;
}

public void setAssociateName(String associateName) {
    this.associateName = associateName;
}

public String getAssociateRole() {
    return associateRole;
}

public void setAssociateRole(String associateRole) {
    this.associateRole = associateRole;
}

public String getAssociateMobileNumber() {
    return associateMobileNumber;
}

public void setAssociateMobileNumber(String associateMobileNumber) {
    this.associateMobileNumber = associateMobileNumber;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "UserLogin [associateId=" + associateId + ", associateName="
            + associateName + ", associateRole=" + associateRole
            + ", associateMobileNumber=" + associateMobileNumber + "]";
}
```

}

Validator Class:

```
public class UserRegisterValidator implements Validator {

@Override
public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {

    return UserLogin.class.equals(clazz);
}

@Override
public void validate(Object user, Errors errors) {
    System.out.println("validator method::" + user);

    ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmpty(errors, "associateId", "associateid_empty");
    ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmpty(errors, "associateName", "associatename_empty");
    ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmpty(errors, "associateRole", "associaterole_empty");
    ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmpty(errors, "associateMobileNumber", "associatemobile_empty");

    /*UserLogin userLogin = (UserLogin)user;
    System.out.println("Validate name condi:" + userLogin);

    if (userLogin.getAssociateId() == null
            || userLogin.getAssociateId().toString().isEmpty()) {

        errors.rejectValue("associateId", "associatesorid_empty");
    }

    String userName = userLogin.getAssociateName();
    if (userName == null || userName.trim().isEmpty()) {

        errors.rejectValue("associateName", "associatename_empty");
    }

    String role = userLogin.getAssociateRole();
    if (role == null || role.trim().isEmpty()) {

        errors.rejectValue("associateRole", "associaterole_empty");
    }

    String mobile = userLogin.getAssociateMobileNumber();

    if (mobile == null || mobile.trim().isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("Error In Mobile NO");
        errors.rejectValue("associateMobileNumber", "associatemobile_empty");
    }

    if (mobile != null && !mobile.matches("[0-9]{10}")) {

        errors.rejectValue("associateMobileNumber",
                "associatemobile_notvalid");
    }*/

}
```

}

MVC Config.xml file

```
<!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing 
    infrastructure -->
<!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
<annotation-driven />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.ames" />

<!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving 
    up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

<!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources 
    in the /WEB-INF/view directory -->
<beans:bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/" />
    <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
    destroy-method="close">

    <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
    <beans:property name="url"
        value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe" />
    <beans:property name="username" value="skill_eval_system" />
    <beans:property name="password" value="skill_eval_system" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
    <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></beans:property>
</beans:bean>



<beans:bean id="assessorDAO" class="com.ames.dao.AssessorDAO">
    <beans:property name="jdbcTemplate" ref="jdbcTemplate"></beans:property>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="assessorService" class="com.ames.service.AssessorService">
    <beans:property name="assessorDAO" ref="assessorDAO"></beans:property>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="messageSource"
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <beans:property name="basename" value="classpath:ValidationMessages_en"></beans:property>
    <beans:property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"></beans:property>
</beans:bean>
<beans:bean id="userRegisterValidator" class="com.ames.validator.UserRegisterValidator"></beans:bean>
```

Controller Class:

```
@Controller
public class RegisterController {
    @Autowired
private IRegisterService registerService;
@Autowired
@Qualifier("userRegisterValidator")
private UserRegisterValidator userRegisterValidator;

 @InitBinder
    private void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
        binder.setValidator(userRegisterValidator);
    }

@RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView register(ModelAndView modelAndView,
        @ModelAttribute("userLogin") UserLogin userLogin) {

    modelAndView.addObject("userLogin", userLogin);
    modelAndView.setViewName("user_register");
    return modelAndView;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/registeruser", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String registerUser(@ModelAttribute("userLogin") UserLogin userLogin,
        ModelAndView modelAndView, BindingResult errors) {
    System.out.println("reg.user.Service::" + userLogin);
    String viewPageName = "";
    UserRegisterValidator userRegisterValidator = new UserRegisterValidator();
    System.out.println(userRegisterValidator.supports(UserLogin.class));
    if (userRegisterValidator.supports(UserLogin.class)) {
        System.out.println("Before Validate In Controller");
        userRegisterValidator.validate(userLogin, errors);
        System.out.println("After Validate Method");
    }
    System.out.println("Eroors?::" + errors.hasErrors());
    if (errors.hasErrors()) {
        System.out.println("Controller IF Condition After Validation");
        viewPageName = "user_register";
    } else {
        System.out.println("From registerUser Method");
        String successUser = registerService.associateRegister(userLogin);

        modelAndView.addObject("successuser", successUser);
        if (successUser == "" || successUser == null) {
            viewPageName = "admin_home";
        } else {
            viewPageName = "admin_home";
        }
    }
    return viewPageName;
}
```

}

properties file:

```
associateid_empty = Enter a valid id
associatename_empty = Enter a valid name
associaterole_empty = Choose a valid role from list
associatemobile_empty = Enter a mobile number
associatemobile_notvalid = Enter a valid mobile number
```

while click on submit with empty data the following error is coming in console as well as browser.
Console data:

```
Sep 24, 2017 10:28:45 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invokeSEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [mvc] in context with path [/Skill_Eval_System] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'associateId' of bean class [org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView]: Bean property 'associateId' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?] with root cause org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'associateId' of bean class [org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView]: Bean property 'associateId' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?   at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:725)
at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:716)
at org.springframework.validation.AbstractPropertyBindingResult.getActualFieldValue(AbstractPropertyBindingResult.java:99)
at org.springframework.validation.AbstractBindingResult.getFieldValue(AbstractBindingResult.java:229)
at org.springframework.validation.ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmpty(ValidationUtils.java:165)
at org.springframework.validation.ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmpty(ValidationUtils.java:108)
at com.ames.validator.UserRegisterValidator.validate(UserRegisterValidator.java:21)
at com.ames.controller.RegisterController.registerUser(RegisterController.java:50)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:689)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:938)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:863)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:94)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:502)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1132)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:684)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1539)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1495)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

**

> Can any one tell me why this exception is comming and give some clarity to overcome this problem? and specify is there any other way to do validations.

Note: please ignore if i am not clear about asking question. im new to stackoverflow.

**

Answer (score 0):

I see you have the following line commented out in your validator:

```
    UserLogin userLogin = (UserLogin)user;
```

What happens if you reintroduce this line in your code?

:)

Comment: Thanks for response @Kaj. Both are works as same for checking empty or not. i just un comment and executes, even thought same exception is coming. just i am validating through errors.rejectValue() method instead of ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmpty(). as per my understanding.

Comment: Good point! You are correct :) I notice ub the stacktrace that the class from which `associateId` is missing is `org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView` and not `UserLogin`. Strange?

Comment: Is there missing a `@Valid` in the line `public String registerUser(@ModelAttribute("userLogin") UserLogin userLogin`, i.e. should it be `public String registerUser(@Valid @ModelAttribute("userLogin") UserLogin userLogin,`?